# How to keep text on Same position while animating it's Font Size? React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-animation

I am working on Text Scaling in which I want to scale the text but with keeping the x position. Now, I am scaling the Text but it's loses it's current position. Can someone help me out with it?

```js
<Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateY: transText }] }}>

                                    <Animated.View onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout: { width, height } } }) => {
                                        label.current = { width, height };
                                    }} style={{ width: width - (width / 3), transform: [{ scale: textScale }, { translateX: labelTransX }, { translateY: labelTransY }], justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handleMenu}>
                                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                                <View>
                                                    <Animated.Text style={{ color: isDarkMode ? colors.TextBodyL : 'black', fontSize: 28, fontWeight: 'bold' }} numberOfLines={1}>
                                                        {mainLabel}
                                                    </Animated.Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ rotate: rotate.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 180], outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'], extrapolate: 'extend' }) }] }}>
                                                    <Icon name={'caret-down-outline'} size={20} color={isDarkMode ? colors.TextBodyL : 'black'} />
                                                </Animated.View>
                                            </View>
                                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                    </Animated.View>

                                    <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateY: labelTransY }] }}>
                                        <Text style={{ color: isDarkMode ? colors.TextBodyL : colors.TextBodyD }}>
                                            {notesState.length} notes
                                        </Text>
                                    </Animated.View>

                                </Animated.View>
```

This code above somehow keeps text to maintain it's position but not too much accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

1. Easy: Put your text in a container with `justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'`
2. More annoying: add negative `marginTop` and `marginLeft` to your animated text properties, but multiply that amount by the change in `fontSize`, multiplied by PixelRatio/fontScale.

Hopefully the first option works for you; if not, let me know if you need more info on the second.